# When to use the word inductance and when to use inductivity?

Tags: inductor, inductance

I sometimes need to fill in revision tables for inductive components and i always stumble upon whether it's "Turns changed. *Inductance* updated." OR "Turns changed. *Inductivity* updated." .

Comment: I can't recall ever using, or even reading, the word "inductivity".

Comment: A German might translate "Induktivität" to "inductivity".

Comment: @CL. since we are located in Germany, this is also my guess.

Comment: @CL: Yes. I guess "inductivity" is inadvertently used by foreign English speakers; especially Germans, because many German terms ending in "-tät" in English end in "-ity" (e.g. Komplexität -> complexity; Relativität -> relativity; ...) and thus Induktivität -> inductivity

Comment: Related terms that Germans commonly (mis-)use in English technical language: “isolator” for _insulator_ and “condensator” for _capacitor_.

Comment: I don't think I've heard the word inductivity before, don't use it, I don't like it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Inductivity is not an used term in EE

(or at least i have never seen it, if anybody has, feel free to downvote add reference)

My guess would be that the tables you refer to either are very old, and thus contain obsolete vocabulary, or were filled/updated by an operator who did not understand the words he was using.

[The wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inductivity) does not make any sense to me either, unless it is an old term for magnetic permeability.

Comment: Unless it's a US reference.... My cousins to the south do seem to love making up new words by adding extensions like that.... drives me batty,

Comment: @Trevor There is no central authority for English words. Why not coin new words and embiggen the language?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany LMAO "embiggen"

Answer (score 5):

We do use resistivity for the material property, and resistance, for when we create a specific size and shape piece of material.

The property of a material that gives rise to inductance, when you pass a piece of wire through or around it to define a volume and shape and form an inductor, is called permeability.

Similarly, a dielectric has permittivity, and you can make a capacitor with a certain capacitance by defining a suitable size and shape with electrodes.

Inductivity sounds like it could be a word, or might have once been, but certainly is not in use now.

Comment: I'm quite certain I've seen *inductivity* used in a paper or article (online) as meaning *inductance* somewhere in the past week. From what I recall, it seemed either an obsolete term (but the paper was not) or an error in translation.